# I'm trying to search column A for the text in quote marks, I should get the cell above when found and place it column C

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to search column A for the text in quote marks, I should get the cell above and place it column C.

```
Sub ALobP3b_LPALLETName()
'
' ALobP3_LPALLETName Macro
'
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(R[1]C[-2]=""STD LTR 3D BC"",RC[-2],IF(R[1]C[-2]=""STD LTR SCF BC"",RC[-2],IF(R[1]C[-2]=""STD LTR NDC BC"",RC[-2],IF(R[1]C[-2]=""STD LTR BC WKG"",RC[-2],IF(R[1]C[-2]=""STD LTR BC/MACH WKG"",RC[-2])))))"
    ' Range("B2").FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C[1]"         'refs A1, one row up (-1) and one column left (-1)              ]
    Range("C1").Select
    Selection.AutoFill destination:=Range("C1:C1000"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("C1:C1000").Select

End Sub
```

I get False in column C for everything.
The formula below shows up in the false

```
=IF(A17="STD LTR 3D BC",A16,IF(A17="STD LTR SCF BC",A16,IF(A17="STD LTR NDC BC",A16,IF(A17="STD LTR BC WKG",A16,IF(A17="STD LTR BC/MACH WKG",A16)))))
```

BROOKLYN NY 112  (a16)
STD LTR 3D BC    (A17)

Answer (score 3):

The following function will return the value cell on top of the first cell with the desired text within the range specified.

To use it you just have to copy the following code as if it was a macro, save the document and then use the formula.

As an example you can use: =search_above("STD LTR 3D BC", A1:A10).
In this example, if the cell A3 is equal to "STD LTR 3D BC" it will return the value of the cell A2.

```
Function search_above(text As String, rng_to_search As Range)

 For Each Cell In rng_to_search
     If Cell.Value = text Then
         search_above = Cells(Cell.Row - 1, Cell.Column).Value
        
     End If
    
 Next Cell

End Function
```

Edit:
With your comment I understand that you want the function to find any of the strings and if it finds 1 of them it should return the text above it.
Here is the updated version of the function to do what you want:

```
Function search_above(rng_to_search As Range)

For Each Cell In rng_to_search

    If Cell.Value = "STD" Or Cell.Value = "LTR" Or Cell.Value = "3D" Or Cell.Value = "BC" Then
       search_above = Cells(Cell.Row - 1, Cell.Column).Value 
    End If

Next Cell

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you, How would I add the 5 different strings to the function and run it?

Comment: I updated the solution. I hope it works as intended now

Answer (score 0):

Why using VBA for something you can do with a simple formula:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$5;MATCH(C3;$A$2:$A$5;0)-1)
```

As in the following screenshot:

[image: Excel screenshot]